# Validate object ID from GET to POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a GET method that allows a user to access a comment they have previously made on my site.  Then I have a post method that lets them update that comment.

My normal solution would be to send the entire `Comment` model through, let them update it, then update it on the database when they POST back.  But this would involve sending the `CommentID` through in a `HiddenFor`, which can easily be manipulated.

How can I verify that the `CommentID` sent in my `GET` method  is the same that I'm getting back in my `POST`, so they are not able to alter any comment they wish?

Comment: Note you can also add the `CommentID` value as a route parameter in the `BeginForm()` as an alternative to using a hidden input (and if you renamed it to `ID`, and your using the default route - its added for you automatically. One way to be sure a hidden field has not been tampered with is to include a hash of the original `ID` (say `IDHash`) in the view model and include a second hidden input for it, then in the POST method, run the hash algorithm on the posted ID and compare it with the posted `IDHash` value.

Comment: But if your app required authentication, why check the user is the author of the comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I verify that the CommentID sent in my GET method is the same
>   that I'm getting back in my POST?

Basically you have to validate following things in your `POST` -

1. User is a logged-in user. So that only authenticated users will post comments.
2. `CommentID` which you get in `POST`, should be a valid `CommentID` and it should present in database.
3. `UserId` associated with Logged-in User should be the same `UserID` which is associated with `Comment`. So basically your `Comment` should also contain `UserId` column, which you can check at the time of update.

To make sure update happens to the comment which has been sent in `GET` -

1. Hold `CommentID` in `Session` and in the `POST` action compare the `CommentID` which you get with the value in `Session`.

Comment: this makes sense, except the last `Session` part.  Isn't that open to manipulation?  The rest of it sounds like the user would only be able to 'hack' their own comments.

Comment: `Isn't that open to manipulation?` Session will be User specific. It cannot be manipulated unless hackers will get to the know the SessionId of a user.

Comment: thanks @ramiramilu, this was very helpful.  I know what I need to do more research on now, and have a clear idea

Comment: @ramiramilu, Session would be a problem if a user has multiple tabs open for editing multiple comments

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Agreed, in that case the object which will be stored in `Session` should be a `List<CommentId>` rather than single `CommentId`.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that this behaviour your are describing is the correct one. Via POSTs and GETs, the API must allow data manipulation using the `CommentID`.

What you are missing is the following: for that to happened, the user must be authenticated and have the appropriate roles. As long as the user is allowed to make these changes there is no problem. Note that, if the user is not authenticated nor authorized, he or she will not be able to execute any of this operations, should authentication and authorization be enforced. If you wish, you can even allow a user with a certain role just to do GETs and not POSTs for this specific case.